# React native error while creating bottom navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to create Bottom Navigation in react native project. I am getting this error

> Invariant violation: Element type is invalid: expected string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for a composite components) but got undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

But I did export to all my files and I didn't mixed with any default or named imports.

### Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import rootReducer from './src/redux/reducers/rootReducer'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'

const store = createStore(rootReducer)

const Root = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
            <App />
        </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
)

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => Root);
```

### App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';

import Accounts from './src/components/Accounts';
import Categories from './src/components/Categories';
import Transactions from './src/components/Transactions';
import Budget from './src/components/Budget';
import Overview from './src/components/Overview';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export default App = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Accounts"
      activeColor="#e91e63"
      labelStyle={{ fontSize: 12 }}
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'tomato' }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Accounts"
        component={Accounts}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Home',
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen ... />
<Tab.Screen ... />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

What is the error in my coding? I have gone through previous questions but all the solutions are changing default to named and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Adding export default solved my problem

```
Code :

//Import library to help create component
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import Header from './src/components/header';

//Create a Component
const App = () => (
  <Header />
);

//Export App - This line solved my issue
export default App;

//Render it to the device
AppRegistry.registerComponent('albums', () => App);
//albums is project name that we use while creating RN App
```